# How to create a completely private wordpress with multiple membership levels

Tags: customization

Hello I would like to create a private WordPress blog for friend and family and I would also require to restrict certain content for only family which the level of friends can't view. It could be entire categories or just a few posts. Is there any plug in that offers such flexibility. I would also like to protect my RSS feed and not allow search engines to index my site.

Also I am using an external writer to create content. Its called ScreenSteps, this also allows me to upload content to my blog, all I did was to activate the XML-RPC option from the writing tab on the settings menu. Will this be affected if I make my blog private using a plugin ?

Comment: So long as you keep the XML-RPC option turned on, you'll still be able to post content.  Every [XML-RPC call](http://mindsharestrategy.com/?tag=xmlrpc) is authenticated based on your username and password ... so it will work even on a private site.

Answer (score 1):

is there a plugin called [Members](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/17/members-wordpress-plugin) created by Justin Tadlock which gives you tools to manage the roles of existing users and to create new roles.

*[Members](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/17/members-wordpress-plugin) has what I call "components." Instead of normal plugin settings, you get the components selection page-That Allows you to choose only the features That You want to use.*